# Twitter Kit for iOS Objective C Installation Problems. 'TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h' file not found error

Tags: objective-c, installation, ios11, twitterkit

I followed **the instruction of 
https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/installation**
Install Twitter Kit Manually (Objective C)
Did all the steps:

1. Downloaded and unzip Twitter Kit.
2. Draged contents to the root of your project in Xcode, and made sure ‘Copy items if needed’ is checked
   [image: Twitter Kit is added on the root as written in the offical installation steps]
3. Initialized the kit inside AppDelegate (with valid key and secret as described)
4. Modified Info.Plist entries as described

=> Trying to compile it gives me an **'TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h' file not found error**: [image: Screenshot of the error]

(I tried it several times...)
**Some step(s) seam(s) to be missing?** 
Thanks for inputs on that.

Comment: Try dragging the content of the "Twitter-Kit-iOS" folder into Xcode, not the folder itself.

Comment: Have you added the framework to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" in the General tab?

Comment: @neuhaus: Thanks. I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: @Sa93: Thanks. I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: Run into news issues: see screenshots below.

Comment: How to migrate the Twitter kit, it using UIWebView. Any input for this Twitter kit sdk.

Answer (score -1):

If you have followed all the instructions, try to do each of the following before trying to build again, as it worked for me once.

- Clean the Project, Cmd + Shift + K
- Restart Xcode
- Restart Computer

If nothing works, then install Twitter Kit through Cocoapods, as it does a clean installation for your frameworks.

Comment: Tried it but didn't work. Cocopod installation gave issues, too. So I continue with the manual installation that should actually work, too.

Answer (score -1):

Since I couldn't edit the original question I add my latest state.

after following instructions of neuhaus and Sau93 I ran into new issues.
Steps 1-5:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]
5. [image]<= **Here is where I stack know ?**